Doing meta-analysis of mediation using structural equation modelling in R, using the “metaSEM” package
I have recently embarked on a project that involves conducting a meta-analysis of mediation using structural equation modelling in R, using the “metaSEM” package.

#stage 1
emo1 <- tssem1(dataemo$data,



           dataemo$n, 



           method = "FEM")




summary(emo1)


#The optimization status is 0, so the estimates are trustworthy.
#stage 2
#A matrix
Build matrix
#We use starting values of  0.2
A <- matrix(c(0            , 0            , 0            ,



          "0.2*CyV_EmR", 0            , 0            ,



          "0.2*CyV_Dep", "0.2*EmR_Dep", 0            ),



        ncol = 3, nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)




Set column and row labels
dimnames(A)[[1]] <- dimnames(A)[[2]] <- c("Cyberbullying Victimisation", "Emotional Regulation", "Depression")
A
Cyberbullying Victimisation Emotional Regulation Depression
Cyberbullying Victimisation "0"                         "0"                  "0"
Emotional Regulation        "0.2CyV_EmR"               "0"                  "0"
Depression                  "0.2CyV_Dep"               "0.2*EmR_Dep"        "0"
A <- as.mxMatrix(A)
#S Matrix
Build matrix
#We use starting values of 0.1
S <- Diag(c(1, "0.1ErrVarE", "0.1ErrVarD"))
Set column and row labels
dimnames(S)[[1]] <- dimnames(S)[[2]] <- c("Cyberbullying Victimisation", "Emotional Regulation", "Depression")
S
Cyberbullying Victimisation Emotional Regulation Depression
Cyberbullying Victimisation "1"                         "0"                  "0"
Emotional Regulation        "0"                         "0.1ErrVarE"        "0"
Depression                  "0"                         "0"                  "0.1ErrVarD"
S <- as.mxMatrix(S)
#model fitting
#list(indirectEffect = mxAlgebra(CyV_EmR*EmR_Dep,name="indirectEffect"))
list(indirectEffect = mxAlgebra(CyV_EmR * EmR_Dep,



                            name="indirectEffect"))



$indirectEffect
mxAlgebra 'indirectEffect'
$formula:  CyV_EmR * EmR_Dep
$result: (not yet computed) <0 x 0 matrix>
dimnames: NULL

emo2 <- tssem2(emo1,



           Amatrix = A, 



           Smatrix = S, 



           intervals.type = "LB", 



           diag.constraints = TRUE,



           mx.algebras = list(indirectEffect = mxAlgebra(CyV_EmR * EmR_Dep,



                                                         name="indirectEffect")))[text]




Rerun
emo2 <- rerun(emo2)
Polite note from mxTryHard: Hessian not checked as model contains mxConstraints

Solution found!  Final fit=3.991833e-27 (started at 8.8658849e-24)  (1 attempt(s): 1 valid, 0 errors)

summary(emo2)

Call:
wls(Cov = coef.tssem1FEM(tssem1.obj), aCov = vcov.tssem1FEM(tssem1.obj),
n = sum(tssem1.obj$n), RAM = RAM, Amatrix = Amatrix, Smatrix = Smatrix,
Fmatrix = Fmatrix, diag.constraints = diag.constraints, cor.analysis = tssem1.obj$cor.analysis,
intervals.type = intervals.type, mx.algebras = mx.algebras,
mxModel.Args = mxModel.Args, subset.variables = subset.variables,
model.name = model.name, suppressWarnings = suppressWarnings,
silent = silent, run = run)
95% confidence intervals: Likelihood-based statistic
Coefficients:
Estimate Std.Error  lbound  ubound z value Pr(>|z|)
CyV_Dep  0.39659        NA 0.37324 0.41984      NA       NA
EmR_Dep  0.22921        NA 0.20286 0.25555      NA       NA
CyV_EmR  0.20812        NA 0.18051 0.23572      NA       NA
ErrVarD  0.75234        NA 0.73078 0.77303      NA       NA
ErrVarE  0.95669        NA 0.94443 0.96743      NA       NA
mxAlgebras objects (and their 95% likelihood-based CIs):
lbound   Estimate     ubound
indirectEffect[1,1] 0.03957306 0.04770226 0.05666786
Goodness-of-fit indices:
Value
Sample size                                 5043
Chi-square of target model                     0
DF of target model                             0
p value of target model                        0
Number of constraints imposed on "Smatrix"     2
DF manually adjusted                           0
Chi-square of independence model            1866
DF of independence model                       3
RMSEA                                          0
RMSEA lower 95% CI                             0
RMSEA upper 95% CI                             0
SRMR                                           0
TLI                                         -Inf
CFI                                            1
AIC                                            0
BIC                                            0
OpenMx status1: 0 ("0" or "1": The optimization is considered fine.
Other values indicate problems.)
I came across an issue indicating that the results of model fitting might not be correct. The result of Goodness-of-fit indices: Chi-square of target model, DF of target model, p value of target model, RMSEA, AIC and BIC are all 0, which are very unusual.
